# Trouble with freshly installed TeXstudio on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: latex

From  scratch (after having removed texlive and texmaker
from the console), I installed TeXstudio with Optional add-ons
latex-beamer
texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-latex-extra

For this, I used Ubuntu Software Center (with the add-ons ticked).
I then took a document which worked perfectly with my old texmaker (on ubuntu 12xx)

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "IC_v5_GHED3".tex
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
Process exited with error(s)
```

Probably a path is missing ... I don't know. Can somebody help ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I think this can be deduced from the compilation message [pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "IC_v5_GHED3".tex kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt].

Comment: @pratnala The system does not find pdflatex.fmt

Comment: @pratnala "sudo which pdflatex.fmt" returns a void answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by purging and reinstalling texlive 
as follows.

`sudo apt-get purge texlive* tex-common*
sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Thank you for your forum, I learned a lot !

Comment: When in doubt, reinstall! (or reboot :P)